# How to use Mahout Streaming K-Means

Tags: cluster-analysis, mahout, k-means

I have seen that there is a new implementation of K-Means in mahout called the Streaming-Kmeans, which achieves the k-means clustering without chained Mapper-Reducer cycles:

https://github.com/dfilimon/mahout/tree/epigrams

I am not finding any articles for the its usage anywhere. Could anyone point out any useful links for its usage, which have some code examples on how to use the same.

Comment: This might help https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1154

Comment: Did you find any useful resources in the meanwhile that you could recommend me?

Comment: That time I actually switched to a Pig UDF and wrote a custom KMeans implementation. Later we moved to Spark.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I can't believe that I cannot find any example for using it...

Answer (score 3):

StreamingKMeans is a new feature in mahout .8. 
For more details, of its algorithms see:
"Streaming  k-means approximation" by N. Ailon, R. Jaiswal, C. Monteleoni
http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips22/NIPS2009_1085.pdf
"Fast and Accurate k-means for Large Datasets" by M. Shindler, A. Wong, A. Meyerson,
http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips24/NIPS2011_1271.pdf

As you mentioned, There is no article for its usage. As other version of clustering algorithm there is a Driver which you can pass some configuration parameters as a string array and it will cluster your data :

```
String[] args1 = new String[] {"-i","/home/name/workspace/XXXXX-vectors/tfidf-vectors","-o","/home/name/workspace/XXXXX-vectors/tfidf-vectors/SKM-Main-result/","--estimatedNumMapClusters","200","--searchSize","2","-k","12", "--numBallKMeansRuns","3",  "--distanceMeasure","org.apache.mahout.common.distance.CosineDistanceMeasure"};

StreamingKMeansDriver.main(args1);
```

for get description of important parameters just do a mistake like "-iiii" as first parameter. it will show you the parameters , their descriptions and default values.

but if you don't want to use it in this way, just read StreamingKMeansMapper, StreamingKmeansReducer, StreamingKmeansThread, these 3 classes code help you understand the usage of algorithm and costumaize it for your need. 
Mapper use StreamingKMeans to produce estimated clusters of input data. for get k final cluster Reducer get intermediate points (the generated centroid in previous step) and by using ballKmeans it cluster these intermediate point to K cluster.

Comment: Are there any extra resources now about streaming kmeans in Mahout?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps for running Streaming k-means:

1. Generate Sparse vectors via seq2sparse.
2. mahout  streamingkmeans  -i ""  -o ""
    --tempDir "" -ow
    -sc org.apache.mahout.math.neighborhood.FastProjectionSearch
    -k  -km

   -k = no of clusters
   -km = (k * log(n))  where k = no. of clusters and n = no. of datapoints to cluster,  round this to the nearest integer

You have option of using a FastProjectionSearch or ProjectionSearch or LocalitySensitiveHashSearch for the -sc parameter.